# Does any of the Greek of Luke 1:1-4 prove that Jesus had stenographers record His words?

Tags: gospel-of-luke, historical-jesus

We read:

> “Inasmuch as many have **taken in hand** to set in order a **narrative** of
> those things which have been fulfilled among us, just as those who
> **from the beginning were eyewitnesses and ministers of the word**
> *delivered them to us*, **it seemed good to me also**, having had perfect
> understanding of all things from the very first, **to write** to you an
> orderly account, most excellent Theophilus, that you may know the
> certainty of those things in which you were instructed.” ‭‭Luke‬
> ‭1:1-4‬ ‭NKJV‬‬

**Q**: **Is there any evidence from ancient history or the Greek text of Luke 1:1-4 that proves Jesus had stenographers record His words?**

(The bolded words in my text presented give a different but consistent flow of arguement that makes it seems that Luke is saying “others wrote of Christ’ words, so I will write as well.”

Comment: “others wrote of Christ’ words, so I will write as well.” - that is exactly what Luke is saying, but what does that have to do with steganographers recording Jesus' words?

Comment: @kutschkem I was reading a book on this called “Jesus Stenographers” & this particular author was arguing based on the Greek text of Luke 1:1-4 that such a text proves the dismissal of the oral tradition theory (Jesus words being passed down telephone game style) & that it also dismisses the whole gospel of Q problem.  Since I haven’t heard many people arguing in favor of such a claim; I wanted to know if anyone else has done their homework in this area.  If Jesus had His words written down as He spoke them from the beginning, then we ACTUALLY do have His words.